# React-native Android app not showing local pictures/assets

Tags: android, image, react-native, compilation, assets

I'm building a react native app and while the iOS version works fine, the android version isn`t showing the assets pictures.

In directory android/app/assets i have a default index.android.bundle and some fonts. (we dont have any images)

I tried

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

but it returned "Module `scheduler` does not exist in the Haste module map"

Gradle version 3.2.1
React-Native version: 0.57.8
React version:16.5.0

Comment: Do you have any answer for that? In my case RN 0.58.4 and R 16.6.3 and older images also stopped showing, even after reverting changes and bringing back older (working) version it's still not showing images. I also suspect problem with bundling.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered similar problem few days ago, in my case it was enough to add in dependencies section of android/app/build.gradle `'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.+'`.

Comment: thx a lot. it worked for me too. u saved me a lot of time. i am curious to know how did u find the solution?

Comment: I compared new project made with react cli with my old one. And found that one dependency is missing.

Comment: @jaroslawj interesting because I have just done the same and I cannot find this in there